# Netlify - Gatsby alias imports not working

Tags: reactjs, webpack, gatsby, alias, netlify

I am getting this error on Netlify build logs:

```
2:24:32 AM: error Generating JavaScript bundles failed
2:24:32 AM: Can't resolve '@layout/PageContainer' in '/opt/build/repo/src/pages/how-it-works'
2:24:32 AM: If you're trying to use a package make sure that '@layout/PageContainer' is installed. If you're trying to use a local file make sure that the path is correct.
2:24:32 AM: error Generating JavaScript bundles failed
2:24:32 AM: Can't resolve '@pages/HowItWorks' in '/opt/build/repo/src/pages/how-it-works'
2:24:32 AM: If you're trying to use a package make sure that '@pages/HowItWorks' is installed. If you're trying to use a local file make sure that the path is correct.
```

I have setup webpack alias like so:

```
// gatsby-node.js
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, actions }) => {
    actions.setWebpackConfig({
        resolve: {
            modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, "src"), "node_modules"],
            alias: {
                "@pages": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/components/pages/"),
                "@layout": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/components/layout/"),
            },
            extensions: [".js", ".json", ".jsx", ".tsx", ".ts"]
        }
    });
};
```

@pages file structure looks like: `src -> components -> pages`

@layout file structure looks like: `src -> components -> layout`

I am able to `yarn build` my repo locally. No issues.

*Once I try to deploy/build with Netlify*, I get this issue with alias. Why does this not work with Netlify specifically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it working, but why it works, I have no clue!!

From what I found out from spending way too much time on this and trying 100 different things.. **Ubuntu** file systems behave very different from Macs/Windows which is why I was able to build locally with no issues (I'm using Windows). Netlify *only* uses Ubuntu image to build, so there was no options of using something else.

It's similar to what was mentioned here: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/2897

**This is what I did to solve my issues:**

```
Rename affected directories:

FROM:
src/components/layout
src/components/pages

TO:
src/components/Layout
src/components/Pages

And then I changed my alias's accordingly:

"@Pages": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/components/Pages")
"@Layout": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/components/Layout")
```

After this I committed my changes to git and ran a new build on Netlify... and like magic it worked!